# ¿Como puedo sacar datos de un vídeo de youtube?

Tags: php

¿Cómo podría sacar los datos de un vídeo de youtube? Por ejemplo título.

En internet encontré varios códigos que a la hora de usarlos daban error o estaban incompletos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el Formato [oembed](http://oembed.com/) (No solo funciona para Youtube) que retornará un `JSON` o `XML` a partir de ahí , te devolverá un `Array` Asociativo con los datos del `vídeo` para que luego puedas obtenerlos individualmente. Haciendo uso de la Biblioteca [curl](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

```
<?php 
 /* Url del Video de Youtube*/
 $url = "URLVIDEO";
 $youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $url ."&format=json";

 $recurso = curl_init($youtube);
 curl_setopt($recurso, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $return = curl_exec($recurso);
 curl_close($recurso);
 print_r(json_decode($return, true));
 /* Acceder al Titulo */
 print_r(json_decode($return, true)['title']);

 ?>
```

> Otra forma sería mediante la  [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started?hl=es-419) de Google

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me ha servido a la prefección!